# How to get the current filtered data from the MUI DataGridPro

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

After applying filters at the DataGridPro, I want to get the current filtered data in order to use it in another component.

I tried to find an event from DataGridPro API documentation but i wasn't able to find something helpful.